# How can I get "RHEL 7.0 vmlinux" file?

Tags: linux, rhel, linux-kernel

I want to use `crash` on `RHEL 7.0`. Since `crash` needs `vmlinux` file, but I can't find it on `/boot` folder, only `vmlinuxz`:

```
......
vmlinuz-0-rescue-7c50639231494746b5dffc0a1ff84727
vmlinuz-3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64
vmlinuz-3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64.debug
......
```

I have installed all kernel*.pkg from `RHEL 7.0 ISO` file:

```
[root@localhost boot]# yum install kernel*
Loaded plugins: product-id, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
RHEL                                                                                        | 4.1 kB  00:00:00
Package kernel-headers-3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package kernel-3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package kernel-abi-whitelists-3.10.0-123.el7.noarch already installed and latest version
Package kernel-debug-3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package kernel-tools-libs-3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package kernel-devel-3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package kernel-debug-devel-3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package kernel-tools-3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

So how can I get `RHEL 7.0 vmlinux` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable 'debuginfo' repository for RHEL and install kernel-debuginfo rpm to get required vmlinux

```
# rpm -qf /usr/lib/debug/lib/modules/3.10.0-229.14.1.el7.x86_64/vmlinux 
kernel-debuginfo-3.10.0-229.14.1.el7.x86_64
```

> Information on how to enable this repo could be found at
>   https://access.redhat.com/solutions/9907